# html download link opens new browser page instead of initiating download - link not working?

Tags: html

I am trying to download my data from instagram. I received the download link, I am clicking the download link and instead of beginning the download of the zip file, a new browser page opens with some html code. I tried it on safari and chrome, same result.
Instagram download page says, "If you requested your information in an HTML format, you'll be able to navigate your files more easily by opening the index.html file first."
I don't know what that means, or if it should be a necessary step.

This is the code that appears on the new browser page:

{"Content-Type":"application/zip","X-Accel-Redirect":"/v/t49.46408-7/126359579_17956263767025403_5110210487620258376_n.zip?efg=eyJ1cmxnZW4iOiJ1cmxnZW5fY3BwX2NsaWVudC9pZy9kaXN0aWxsZXJ5In0\u0026ccb=12-4\u0026oh=00_AT8VV-_GKThuvUaGigs-uVwo8Vfj_j-mZxUmF7hb27VPjg\u0026oe=632636A5\u0026_nc_sid=90810c","Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename="jacobesnake_20220913.zip"","X-FB-Encryption":"k=C0O9J8jeEPW8SKwyFjVRu7n_R8wyAa1ZdN0lyh6WrvY;n=5FYOIoH2ui1_aC4OviHHEsNF3fjmqTlhHuyViRGTS1c;c=512;v=1;l=30335341","status":"ok"}

I'm not sure if that helps. I can't find any answers on youtube google etc. - I am not a programmer or coding expert. Please help!

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for solving programming problems. It isn't customer service for Instagram. If you've found a bug with their site then you need to discuss it with their customer service.

Answer (score -2):

Hey only thing I can kinda see is that there is a redirect in that link, so it looks to be taking you somewhere else. It also looks to be an encrypted Zip file so also look at that.

Sorry I can't be further help